# Problem with my short Unix Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

What can I do to fix this problem? I'm new to emacs, Unix, and makefiles. Please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it. I'm sure it's a simple problem

```
progA: yesno.h yesno.cpp
       g++ -DDEBUG -c yesno.cpp yesno.h
progB: guess.cpp
       g++ -DDEBUG -c guess.cpp
progC: yesno.o guess.o
       g++ -DDEBUG -o guess guess.o yesno.o
```

My error is:

```
Your makefile does too much work when only guess.cpp has been changed:
g++ -c yesno.cpp yesno.h
g++ -c guess.cpp
g++ -o guess guess.o yesno.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile would recompile everything each time.

You don't need the first four lines; `make` knows how to create object files from source.  Or, alternatively, you need to revise those 4 lines into 2, and put them at the end, and change the target names:

```
guess: yesno.o guess.o
        g++ -o guess yesno.o guess.o
guess.o: yesno.h
yesno.o: yesno.h
```

The first target is the one that is built by default, so that ensures that `guess` (the program) is built.  The command line omits the `-DDEBUG` since that only affects source code compilation and there is no source in that link line (though, if using macros as one would in an advanced `makefile`, I'd be fine with the options such as `-DDEBUG` appearing in the link line).

The third line says that `guess.o` depends on `yesno.h`; this is a guess (on my part).  The `make` program already knows how to convert `guess.cpp` to `guess.o`; it just needs the extra information that it also uses the `yesno.h` header.  (If it doesn't, how does it know about the functions defined in `yesno.cpp`?)

The last line says that `yesno.o` depends on `yesno.h`; again, `make` knows how to compile `yesno.cpp` to `yesno.o` but needs the extra information about the header.

This should only recompile `guess.o` when only `guess.cpp` changes; it should only recompile `yesno.o` when `yesno.cpp` changes; it should recompile both object files when `yesno.h` changes.  If any of the source files changes, the program will be relinked; if no source files change, then the `make` command should do nothing (or simply report that there is nothing to do).

Comment: Thank You very much! Problem solved, thanks also for a thorough explanation.